# How do I define a preprocessor symbols in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I wrote `#if TEST_APP` in my code. Now I would like to define TEST_APP. How do I set it using Visual Studio 2010? This is a Windows Forms application.

What is the name of the symbol that is set in a Windows Forms project and in a web project?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Visual Studio [Solution Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools), right-click on a project and click *Properties*. Open the build tab and you will see a field "Conditional compilation symbols". This is a comma-separated list, or space-separated.
There are also two checkboxes for commonly used symbols, DEBUG and TRACE.

For your web projects, you could set the field to "WEB_PROJECT" and Windows Forms to "WINFORMS_PROJECT"

Comment: You can also set these things directly in your project file(*.csproj) for example `<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>` inside a PropertyGroup.

Answer (score 8):

In the Build tab of the properties page for the project, look for the "Conditional compilation symbols" setting.

I don't believe there are any different symbols defined by default for web and Windows Forms applications. Bear in mind this is set for the project itself, and won't affect any class libraries—so I'd expect any code within a project to really know whether it's in a Windows application or not to start with. What were you thinking of using this for?

Comment: after writing APP_TEST -dAPP_TEST (i am thinking gcc) and them fail and after seeing these answers i realize i had a reference to my web lib instead of including my files. oops. That was when i tried getting F# and C# to define methods in the same partial class.

Comment: I dont need the app and web define, i just wondered since i know C++ does it. I am testing some backend code in an app so i can modify it on the fly which i cant do in a web application (Changes are not allowed in the following case. Debugger attached to an already running process)

Comment: We used this in a webapplication to enable caching in debug. In Release caching logic was enabled, in debug disabled but sometimes you want to test caching logic (in debug). For this is an extra conditional is handy. (DEBUG | DEBUG_WITH_CACHE)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
#define TEST_APP true
#if TEST_APP == true
#endif
```

Method 2:

```
#define TEST_APP
#if defined(TEST_APP)
#endif
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxhs2ty(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about C#, not C++? According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives, C# does not support values for defined symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your conditional compilation to dynamically reflect the build or environment conditions, check my answer to **[How do I set a conditional compile variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442076/147511)** on Stack Overflow. I show how to enable conditional compilation based on ambient conditions, such as **C# language version**, so that you can write code like this:

```
#if CSHARP7
    ref T pi = ref rg[i], pj = ref rg[j];
    var t = pi;            // Swap elements: managed pointers
    pi = pj;
    pj = t;
#else
    var t = rg[i];         // Swap elements: clunky
    rg[i] = rg[j];
    rg[j] = t;
#endif
```