# Is it possible to change structure of class via attributes?

Tags: c#, reflection

Now I am reading "CLR via C#" book, and I am interested in following question - Is it possible to change structure of class via attributes like this:

```
[UseFooAttr(true)]
class A
{
  if (IsDefined(typeof(UseFooAttr)))
    public Foo FooProperty{get; set}
};
```

But I am not sure, that this approach has some real benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible. But you may want to use [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if):

```
#define UseFooPropertery // define pre-processor symbol
   class A
   {
#if UseFooProperty // check if symbol is defined
       public Foo FooProperty{get; set}
#endif
   }
```

---

Instead of the `#if/#endif` preprocessor directives you can also use the [`Conditional`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute) attribute:

```
#define UseFooPropertery // define pre-processor symbol
   class A
   {
       [Conditional("UseFooPropertery")]
       public Foo FooProperty{get; set}
   }
```

---

You probably want to [define the symbol in your project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2355359/5528593) instead of putting them in your code.