# What is "#if" directive used for in c# and what "symbols" stand for?

Tags: c#, .net, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to understand how `#if` statement works on C# and how it is used.

After reading [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if), I have got to the conclusion that it is used to compile the code in it if the "symbol" in the condition is defined.

```cs
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

The problem here is that I don't know what they mean by "symbol" (in this case, `DEBUG`), and I'm struggling to find an answer due to the wide meaning of this word.

What are these "symbols" and what is the purpose of these "preprocessor directives"?

Comment: Those are *PreProcessor Directives*

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355340/how-do-i-define-a-preprocessor-symbols-in-c-sharp-visual-studios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As folks already said, it is a pre-processor directive. Code inside the `#if DEBUG ... #endif` will get *conditionally compiled*, depending on whether the symbol `DEBUG` is defined.

In this case, `DEBUG` is simply a symbolic name introduced *specifically* for the pre-processor so that it can distinguish blocks of code that should or should not be compiled.

You can define a new pre-processor symbol in the project settings:

[image: Project settings dialog]

Here, we have a total of four symbols defined:

- `DEBUG`
- `TRACE`
- `ANOTHER_SYMBOL`
- `YET_ANOTHER_SYMBOL`

`DEBUG` and `TRACE` are kind of special because they are so widespread. This is why they have dedicated checkboxes. The term "constant" here is used interchangeably with the term "symbol". However, I hear "symbol" more frequently in this particular context.

Another way to define a symbol is through code. You can add `#define` directives *at the very beginning* of your .cs source files:

```
#define YET_ANOTHER_SYMBOL
```

Comment: One advantage of using the project properties is that you can have different symbols for "release" versus "debug" build configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Those are *PreProcessor Directives*. In your case, it will check if the `DEBUG` symbol is defined saying `#define DEBUG` then the piece of code `Console.WriteLine` will gets executed

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

Comment: The question doesn´t seem to be what a directive actually is, but what a **symbol** is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As you already assumed the `DEBUG`-symbol is **used by the compiler** in order to either translate the code or not. So in a release-build - where `DEBUG` doesn´t exist - the code is not compiled into IL.

A symbol here means a variable introduced **to the compiler**. Those are defined in VS Project Properties-->Build-->conditional complation symbols. However there exists a set of pre-defined symbols - such as `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the predefined, you can also define your own conditional compilation symbol either at the file-level or the project level:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

e.g, type this at the start of the file to define "CONDITION1"

```
#define CONDITION1
```

or define them under the project properties-->build-->Conditional compilation symbols.
Here you can also see the "debug" and "trace" constants predefined (if checked for your config).

Answer (score 0):

"Symbols" in this context means identifiers that are called "conditional compilation symbols" and are only useful for the #if directive.

You can set them:

- In VS from Project properties->build->conditional compilation symbols (as @HimBromBreere wrote) note that there are checkboxes for the commonly used DEBUG and TRACE symbols
- From the compiler command line with the -define option
- In the code with the #define directive